# How do I redirect www.*.example.com to *.example.com?

Tags: nginx, dns, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

Some of our users prepend www to subdomains on our site, which gives them an SSL error because of course the certificate only covers *.example.com. Is there a way to redirect to only one level of subdomain, either in DNS records or through Nginx?

Comment: You should get a certificate that is either a wildcard domain certificate . From [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/510578/how-to-redirect-from-https-www-example-com-to-be-https-example-com)

Comment: @Ajinkya Bawaskar, we're already using a wildcard certificate for \*.example.com, but this does not cover \*.\*.example.com, and as far as I know, that's not possible (at least with LetsEncrypt)

Comment: Well, in that case [this](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2818.txt) says that you can't have `*.*.example.com` covered.

Comment: Yeah that's not my question though, I just want to redirect to \*.example.com, which is covered. The https redirect is also in nginx. To be clear, I don't want to cover \*.\*.example.com.